# Object.keys forEach returns undefined

Tags: javascript

I have the following function which takes in an object as an argument and uses it to manipulate the object

```
function manipulateData(obj){
    var data = Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(index){
         //Perform the manipulation 
         return obj;
    }

    return data;
}
```

I invoke the above function in another callback function, as following

```
converter.on('done', function(jsonArray){
    var newObj = manipulateData(jsonArray);
});
```

Upon debugging i notice that the value returned from the forEach is "undefined", how can i get the data to be returned as expected?

Comment: depends on what you expect to be returned

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`forEach` doesn't return anything. If you want to make a new `Array` by transforming the existing one, [use `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use .map() as this returns a new Array?

```
function manipulateData(obj){
    var data = Object.keys(obj).map(function(index){
         //Perform the manipulation 
         return obj;
    }

    return data;
}
```